# how unzip mutiple zip file with same name in python

Tags: python

I have some zip files whenever I unzip them, the name is the same, how can I unzip them via python?
here is my code:

```
# specifying the zip file name
file_name_1 = "D:/PS files/file from VDI/from VGS/Gy/mash.zip"
file_name_2 = "D:/PS files/file from VDI/from VGS/Gy/mash.1.zip"

# opening the zip file in READ mode
with ZipFile(file_name_1,file_name_2 'r') as zip:
    # printing all the contents of the zip file
    zip.printdir()

    # extracting all the files
    print('Extracting all the files now...')
    zip.extractall('D:/PS files/file from VDI/from VGS/Gy')
print('completed!!!')
```

with below error:

```
with ZipFile(file_name_1,file_name_2 'r') as zip:
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: There is a comma missing at the ^

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the whole code snippet without comments?

There needs to be a comma before the 'r' :
with ZipFile(file_name_1,file_name_2, 'r') as zip:
^

Comment: file_name_1 = "D:/PS files/file from VDI/from VGS/Gy/mash.zip"
file_name_2 = "D:/PS files/file from VDI/from VGS/Gy/mash.1.zip"


zip= ZipFile(file_name_1,file_name_2,'r')
 
    zip.printdir()


    print('Extracting all the files now...')
    zip.extractall('D:/PS files/file from VDI/from VGS/Gy')
print('completed!!!')